# Regex: Match Specific Character in Parentheses

Tags: regex, adobe-indesign

I have the following string:

```
Character (ccdd)
```

The c's and d's are necessary for a stupid design reason. I want to highlight c's and d's specifically, so that

a) matches "cc"
and
b) matches "dd"

with the requirement that it only matches if it is in parentheses.

But I just don't get to it. The only thing I managed so far is:

```
(?<=\()[c]+?(?=\))
```

Edit: To further clarify. I need to apply two separate styles to c's and d's in parentheses in InDesign. Therefore I am looking for two separate regex expressions, one that matches all c's in the parentheses and one that matches all d's.

Anyone an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: can you confirm one thing:- check where `\G` works in indesign?

Comment: [`(?<=\([^()]*)c+(?=[^()]*\))`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5c(%5b%5e()%5d*)c%2b(%3f%3d%5b%5e()%5d*%5c))&i=Character+(ccdd)) - if infinite width lookarounds are supported.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do. Is the string you want to match always `(ccdd)`? Then you can use that as a literal pattern.

Comment: if `\G` is supported:- **[`(?:\(|\G(?!\A)).*?((\w)\2)`](https://regex101.com/r/jZ8zG0/1)**

Comment: You guys are quick! @rock321987 doesn't show any matches in InDesign, neither does Wiktor Stribiżew solution. \G is not supported unfortunately, as far as I can see. I should have been more precise: I am looking for two regex expressions, one that matches all c's in the parentheses and one that matches all d's in the parentheses (so basically one but just for each character)

Comment: Try a hack `c+(?=[^()]*\))` and `d+(?=[^()]*\))`

Comment: Works beautifully, @WiktorStribiżew. Thank you so much, and to all the others. Do you wanna post it as answer for others to see?

Comment: I aded the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the infinite lookbehind and `\G` are not supported, I suggest using a hack: just checking if the `c`s or `d`s are followed with a closing parenthesis.

Use

```
c+(?=[^()]*\))
```

and

```
d+(?=[^()]*\))
```

That hack will work if the parentheses are well balanced and if there are no nested parentheses.

Comment: The latest versions of InDesign support `\K`. Can that be used as an alternative for your `\G` solution? (I don't know what `\G` does but it sounds pretty much the same.)

Comment: `\K` omits all the text in a match buffer. If `\K` is supported, `\G` (matches the beginning of a string or the end of the previous match). It could be matched with some pattern like [`(?:\(|(?!^)\G)[^()]*?\Kc+(?=[^()]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/lI9hW9/1).